# Earliest possible zepplin

Tags: internal-consistency, culture, medieval, airships

In the world I am building the people use large powered blimps. They do have a good reason for using these. What I'm Asking is when could people earliest make blimps If planes didn't happen.

Comment: A zeppelin (or dirigible) is different than a blimp. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean the Wright's brothers switch to doing entertainment business performing for a circus instead? well at least they never failed to make people laugh only this time the audiences are underage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blimps or airships are difficult things. Helium is hard to get, hydrogen is explosive, and hot air doesn't lift much.

Hot air balloons were available from [1783](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_air_balloon#First_manned_flight). They didn't have enough payload to carry an engine.

Hydrogen balloons came [not much later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balloon_%28aeronautics%29#Gas_balloons), but without much payload at first. That balloon needs a sufficiently powerful engine. There was a powered airship in [1852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giffard_dirigible).

An alternative history could have airships a few years before, but a lightweight steam engine requires metallurgy and precision engineering.